# hiddenfield flask not validating

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

Why doesn't the value='ahhhh!' work as a filler.  instead, it says form validation required.

```
<form class="form form-inline" method="post" role="gform" id='gform'>
{{ gform.hidden_tag() }}
{{ wtf.form_errors(gform) }}
{{ wtf.form_field(gform.goal) }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(gform.GHF(value='AHHHHH!')) }}
{{ wtf.form_field(gform.submit) }} 
</form>
```

form

```
class goal_form(Form):
    goal = TextField('goal', validators = [Required()])
    GHF =HiddenField('', validators = [Required()])
    submit=SubmitField('add goal')
```

view

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    gform=goal_form()
    P=models.Projects.query.all()
    if gform.validate_on_submit():
        u=models.Projects.query.get(1)
        p=models.Goals(goal=gform.goal.data,proj=u)
        db.session.add(p)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template("index.html",gform=gform,P=P)
 from app import db
```

I'm just trying to pass validation with a hard coded value.  once it works, I'll put in something that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template `wtf.form_field` is supposed to take in a field, but when you call `gform.GHF(value='AHHHHH!')`, that creates a string. So try passing in the value to GHF in the view rather than in the template.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    gform=goal_form()
    P=models.Projects.query.all()
    if gform.validate_on_submit():
        u=models.Projects.query.get(1)
        p=models.Goals(goal=gform.goal.data,proj=u)
        db.session.add(p)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    gform.GHF.data = 'AHHHHH!'
    return render_template("index.html", gform=gform, P=P)
 from app import db
```

Or you can set a default in the form:

```
class goal_form(Form):
    goal = TextField('goal', validators=[Required()])
    GHF = HiddenField('', default='AHHHHH!', validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('add goal')
```

Comment: That does work, however, I'm trying to have the hidden field=the name of the project, so i can assign the submitted goal to the correct Projects obj in my database.  any idea how to set the value using jinja2?

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't know the name of the project in the view (i.e. the template should be dumb and not need to change data), but in jinja2 you can do `{% set gform.GHF.data = 'AHHHHH!' %}{{ wtf.form_field(gform.GHF) }}`.